# update and delete firestore data and firebase storage asynchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js

I have a `crud` for storing data included image. It consist of `name`, `type`, `qty`, `description`, and `url`. Url in here is to storing image url, that the image has been stored before data and resulting an url.

Here's the code for create method:

```
//useState() hook captures the value from the input value
    const [url, setUrl] = useState("")

    const fileButton = (e) => {

        // get the file
        var file = e.target.files[0];

        const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images/' + file.name).put(file);

        // Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
        storageRef.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
            function (snapshot) {
                // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
                var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
                switch (snapshot.state) {
                    case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
                        console.log('Upload is paused');
                        break;
                    case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
                        console.log('Upload is running');
                        break;
                }
            }, function (error) {

                // A full list of error codes is available at
                // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
                switch (error.code) {
                    case 'storage/unauthorized':
                        // User doesn't have permission to access the object
                        break;

                    case 'storage/canceled':
                        // User canceled the upload
                        break;


                    case 'storage/unknown':
                        // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
                        break;
                }
            }, function () {
                // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
                storageRef.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function (downloadURL) {
                    console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
                    setUrl(downloadURL)
                })
            })
    }

    /* The onSubmit function we takes the 'e' 
      or event and submits it to Firebase
      */
    const onSubmit = e => {
        /* 
        preventDefault is important because it 
        prevents the whole page from reloading
        */
        e.preventDefault();

        firebase.firestore().collection("items").add({url})
            //then will reset the form to nothing
            .then(() => setUrl(""));
    };
```

The feature that I don't have now is `update` & `delete` for url, I've tried to follow the create method for update method and url's not change. Below is the update method's code:

```
const UpdateItem = ({ setEditing, currentItem, updateItem }) => {
    /*
    Sets the state of the item to the current item
    */
    const [item, setItem] = useState(currentItem);

    useEffect(() => {
        setItem(currentItem);
        setUrl("")
        console.log("useEffect passes the currentItem: ", currentItem);
    }, [currentItem]);

    const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("onSubmit passes the id and items", item);
        updateItem({ currentItem }, item);
    };

    const onChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setItem({ ...item, [name]: value })
    };

    return (
        <>
            <h2>Update Item</h2>
            <div className="file-div">
                <font>Upload your image</font>
                <label className="file-label">
                    <input type="file" onChange={fileButton} />
                    <span>+</span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <label htmlFor="Update Item">Update Item:</label>
               
                <input
                    value={item.url}
                    name="url"
                    onChange={onchange}
                    type="text"
                    hidden={true}
                />
                <button>Update</button>
                <button onClick={() => setEditing(false)}>Cancel</button>
            </form>
        </>
    );
};
```

And this is the list item code (in here, the stored value url is used in `<img src={item.url}>`):

```
const useItems = () => {
    //useState() hook, sets initial state to an empty array
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = firebase
            .firestore() //access firestore
            .collection("items") //access "items" collection
            .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                //You can "listen" to a document with the onSnapshot() method.
                const listItems = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                    //map each document into snapshot
                    id: doc.id, //id and data pushed into items array
                    ...doc.data() //spread operator merges data to id.
                }));
                setItems(listItems); //items is equal to listItems
            });
        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);
    return items;
};
const deleteItem = id => {
    firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("items")
        .doc(id)
        .delete();
};
const ItemList = ({ editItem }) => {
    const listItem = useItems();
    return (
        <table className="tg">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td className="tg-a02x">Image</td>
                    <td className="tg-6hdc"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            {listItem.map(item => (
                <tbody key={item.id}>
                    <tr>
                        <td className="tg-a02x">
                            <img width="50" height="50" src={item.url} />
                        </td>
                        <td className="tg-6hdc">
                            <button onClick={() => editItem(item)}>Edit</button>
                            <button onClick={() => deleteItem(item.id)}>Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            ))}
        </table>
    );
};
export default ItemList;
```

**NOTE:

- I already imported `React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";` &
  `import firebase from "../firebase";` for each of that files
- in code, I'm just using `url` field for code not too long

Comment: On Stack Overflow, all of the relevant code must be contained within the question itself.  Do not link to external resources, as those might become stale, rendering this question useless for others in the future.

Comment: doesn't that make it easier for developers not to write code twice? after all, my inserted link already producting code

Comment: Just edit the question to copy and paste the relevant code into the question. It's a site policy: "Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included in the question itself". Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thanks, I already updated my codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `update()` api of Firestore

Please refer more from here.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data

Deleting data is also documented as below.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data